# How to detect a phablet from client or server side

Tags: javascript, java, spring, user-agent, device-detection

I'm currently using [LiteDeviceResolver](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.mobile/spring-mobile-device/1.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/mobile/device/LiteDeviceResolver.java) to detect the device used by a customer on a website developed in Java.

It works well to differenciate mobile from desktop.

However, now I need to detect phablet. Currently phablet are considered as desktop device instead of mobile.

I can't find out a list of know user-agent for phablet.

I'm looking for any advice to detect efficiently all known phablet.
Either using code or UA list, from client side or server side.

Comment: Advice: Don't do that and use responsive design. Further, there's no clear difference between phones, phablets, and tablets, so UA sniffing is unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks but the website has different functionalities for mobile and phablet users. It's not just a matter of design. Also I'm looking toward all possible solutions, from client or server side, using UA or not. Currently I guess the only solution I have is to check in js the screen size and deduce from that the device.

Comment: I think the big question I have (and this might be naïveté) but is there a firm, quantitative definition of a "phablet?" I always assumed it was a "know it when you see it" kind of thing.

Comment: "Mobile" is a phone. "Phablet" is a phone with a bit bigger screen. "Different functionalities" for these two is... questionable.